# custom parallelism apache spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, parallel-processing

I am learning from [the book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449358624). The book has concept of custom parallelism and i dont get it at all. What is the difference between abc and abcd? I printed them using abcd.collect() and abc.collect() and the output is the same. Is abcd calculated faster?

```
data = [("a", 3), ("b", 4), ("a", 1)]
abc=sc.parallelize(data).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)      # Default parallelism
abcd=sc.parallelize(data).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y, 10)  # Custom parallelism
```

Answer (score 0):

The result after a `collect` should be the same. Whether it is faster or not depends. The first form, i.e.

```
abc = sc.parallelize(data).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
```

will produce a result which is either partitioned in the same manner as `data` (if `data` has a `Partitioner`) or will otherwise default to a `HashPartition` where the number of partitions is equal to `defaultParallelism` (or something like this.)

In the second form, i.e.

```
abcd=sc.parallelize(data).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y, 10)
```

you're telling Spark to use a `HashPartitioner` with 10 partitions. So this second form gives you explicit control over the degree of parallelism (or enables you to change it) used in the aggregation.

If you have lots of keys it might be a good idea to spread out the work of aggregating things out more (so more partitions), especially if what your aggregating (per key) is large, as this can reduce communication bottlenecks for large clusters.

Comment: can i control key-wise splitting of data. For example if i have 10 keys, can i say that data belonging to each key should be on a single machine given that i have 10 machines to store my data?